# A jQuery plugin for html zoom/pan (like gmap)

Tags: jquery

I'd like to pan and zoom arbitrary html in a similar way that google maps behaves (btw, I see how you can use google maps API with custom images -- not possible with any html content right?)

I see a lot of jquery plugins for panning images, is there any designed for html?

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

http://codecanyon.net/item/smooth-zoom-pan-jquery-image-viewer/511142?ref=lvraa

However, it is not free. Does anybody know a free plugin to achieve a similar pan?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the answer above because it is not open source. There are many open source ones, the one I ended up using is:

http://benlumley.co.uk/dev/panzoom/example/index.html